# STRING_AGG substitute for SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have populated a new table and I need to aggregate a column without using the string_agg function as this is SQL Server 2008 (old data).

Looks something like this:

```
id      file       type        created 
---------------------------------------
1       xyz1.pdf     A           4/06
1       xyz2.pdf     A           4/06
1       xyz3.pdf     A           4/06
2       abc.pdf      A           4/06
2       abc1.pdf     A           4/06
3       123.pdf      A           4/06
```

I need this:

```
id      file                          type        created 
----------------------------------------------------------
1       xyz1.pdf;xyz2.pdf;xyz3.pdf      A           4/06
2       abc.pdf;abc1.pdf                A           4/06
3       123.pdf                         A           4/06
```

I'm pretty new to this so explicit instructions would be necessary

Thanks!

Comment: A quick google shows that this question has been asked many many times before. Please do your research before asking us to spend our time assisting.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 is, however, End of Life and has been for over a year. The *real* solution is upgrade to a supported version. Both the latest versions support `STRING_AGG`.